# cuda-gdb does not step into kernels

Tags: cuda, cuda-gdb

I am trying to get memory traces from cuda-gdb. However, I am not able to step into the kernel code. I use the nvcc flags -g -G and -keep but to no effect. I am able to put a breakpoint on the kernel function but when I try to access the next instruction, it jump to the end of the kernel function. I have tried this on the sdk examples and I observe the same behaviour. I am working on cuda 5 toolkit. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is typical for kernel launch failure. Make sure you check return codes of the CUDA calls. Note that for debugging you may want to add additional call `cudaDeviceSynchronize` immediately after the kernel call and to check the return code from this call - it is the most precise way to obtain the cause of the asynchronous kernel launch failure.

**Update:** The code running outside of debugger but not in cuda-gdb most often is caused by trying to debug on a single-GPU system from graphical environment. cuda-gdb cannot share GPU with Xwindows as this would hang the OS.

You need to exit the graphical environment (e.g. quit X window) and debug from the console if your system only has one GPU.

If you have a multi-GPU system, then you should check your Xwindow configuration (Xorg.conf) so it does not use the GPU you reserve for debugging.

Comment: yes the code works outside of the debugger. Its an sdk example and it executes correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the problem was. I was running the CUDA application on the same GPU that runs my device. Thanks!